# Light Weight Edge

Tags: graph, orientdb, database, nosql

Can you define Light Weight Edge Properly?
Just make a short example about the concept of Light Weight Edge that you have in your mind?
What is the importance of Light weight edge in Graphs and What are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Working-with-graphs.html#lightweight-edges):

Lightweight edges

Starting from OrientDB v1.4.x edges, by default, are managed as lightweight edges: they don't have own identities as record, but are physically stored as links inside vertices. OrientDB automatically uses Lightweight edges only when edges have no properties, otherwise regular edges are used. From the logic point of view, lightweight edges are edges at all the effects, so all the graph functions work correctly. This is to improve performance and reduce the space on disk. But as a consequence, since lightweight edges don't exist as separate records in the database, the following query will not return the lightweight edges:

SELECT FROM E
In most of the cases Edges are used from Vertices, so this doesn't cause any particular problem. In case you need to query Edges directly, even those with no properties, disable lightweight edge feature by executing this command once:

ALTER DATABASE CUSTOM useLightweightEdges=false
This will only take effect for new edges. For more information look at: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Troubleshooting#why-i-cant-see-all-the-edges.

For more information look at Graph API.